Grid, Flex gap between boxes
I have a question what is better to use?
Grid box or flex for folding directly under itself without a gap that takes into account the height of others in the line.
I need to make the boxes right next to each other and the ones underneath.
Row code
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto; 
  grid-auto-flow: dense; 
  gap: 10px; 


How can I possibly resolve this?

Maybe flex-box?

How with flex-box?

Read the duplicate question. What you try to do is called masonry grid/layout. It is only supported as grid by FF in experimental mode. So you won't come around flexbox. Nevertheless, the way you ask your question it would be in most cases be closed as opinion-based. Better ask how to do it rather then asking what would be better.

@goalTosin please read [ask]. A codepen alone would not be allowed. Asking to include code might be useful but the 2nd part would be against the guidelines. Beside that, this question does not need code as it is purely conceptional. Depending on what you would use (grid or flexbox) the DOM structure would be completely different. But as said, the question is not about how to do it but what would be better.
